# In Ocaml, how do I avoid an unused variable warning if I don't want to use the variable?

Tags: ocaml

Say I'm defining a recursive function on lists that looks something like:

```ml
let rec listFunc xs =
    match xs with
    | [] -> aThing
    | h :: t -> listFunc (tailFunc t)
;;
```

where `tailFunc` is some other function from lists to lists. The compiler will give me an unused variable warning since I didn't use `h`, but I can't just use the wildcard since I need to be able to access the tail of the list. How do I prevent the compiler from giving me a warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prefix the `h` with an underscore.

```
let rec listFunc xs =
    match xs with
    | [] -> aThing
    | _h :: t -> listFunc (tailFunc t)
;;
```

or simply:

```
let rec listFunc xs =
    match xs with
    | [] -> aThing
    | _ :: t -> listFunc (tailFunc t)
;;
```

Any binding that starts with `_` won't be in scope and won't give you unused  variable warnings.

Comment: only for information... is this anywhere in the documentation ? I may have missed it until now, but this is good info. I find same semantics even in `Erlang`.. so just curious...

Comment: I personally learned OCaml by learning ReasonML (which has since been rebranded to ReScript) and first learned about the underscore prefix here: https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/pattern-matching#safeguards (and also through practical experience)

Comment: Thanks.. :-D .. Even I'm gonna try once I open the REPL... :-D. `_` I was aware of, but `underscored names`(`_some_name`) I was not, or haven't tried yet!!!